# How to prove that the solution of a differential equation is bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider in $\mathbb{R}$ the Cauchy problem:
$$(*) \quad x'(t)=\frac{1}{1+t^2+x^2(t)} \quad, \quad x(0)=0$$
Show that the solution of $(*)$ is bounded.

We know that the unique solution $\psi(t)$ of $(*)$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and it's an odd function, but how to prove that $\psi(t)$ is bounded ?

Comment: Find $x'(t) \leq \mbox{SomethingNice(t)}$.

Comment: @Michael  oh i see, i didn't think this way, i was doing $x'(t)<1$ but i got nothing, but now i see that $x'(t) \leq \frac{1}{1+t^2}$ which give us for all $t \in \mathbb{R}^*$ $x(t)\leq arctan(t)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ , is that true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x'(t)$ is always positive, it follows that $x(t)$ is strictly increasing.

Hence, since $x(0)=0$, it follows that $x(t)$ is positive if $t > 0$ 
and $x(t)$ is negative if $t < 0$.

Let $y(t)=\tan^{-1}(t)-x(t)$.

Then
$$
y'(t)
=
\frac{1}{1+t^2}
-
\frac{1}{1+t^2+x^2(t)}
\ge 
0
$$
hence $y$ is non-decreasing.

Thus, since $y(0)=0$, it follows that $y(t)\ge 0$ for $t\ge 0$ and $y(t)\le 0$ for $t\le 0$.

Then for $t\ge 0$ we get
$$
0\le x(t)\le \tan^{-1}(t) < \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and for $t\le 0$ we get
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2} < \tan^{-1}(t) \le x(t)\le 0
$$
Therefore $x(t)$ is bounded.